# How to create a matrix for input string in SciKitLearn module of Python?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I have used https://github.com/yassersouri/classify-text to check the efficiency of various algorithms available in Scikitlearn. Now, I know there are following steps in classification

> 1. Create a matrix of training data and corresponding classes
> 2. Train a classifier on the basis of these matrices
> 3. Divide the training set into training/test

Now, I would like to skip the step 3 (which I have already done) and take the input from user and test it against the trained variable.

Now I am not sure what is the next step after taking input from console, do I need to build BOW matrix for this string as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you need to run your new string through the *same* bag-of-words transformer that you used for your training data.

If you are using scikit-learn, I'd recommend the scikit-learn feature extraction tools directly rather than the utility routines at the link you gave. If you [click through that repository](https://github.com/yassersouri/classify-text/blob/master/util.py#L108), you'll find it uses scikit-learn's [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to compute the bag-of-words representation.

The canonical way to use such a vectorizer is within a pipeline, and at that point the prediction on new data is straightforward. Here's a simple example, where I have left-out the cross-validation aspect for simpliticy:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

corpus = ['this document is about cheese',
          'this is about snakes',
          'another one about cheese',
          'and another one about snakes']
label = ['cheese', 'snakes', 'cheese', 'snakes']

clf = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())
clf.fit(corpus, label)
predicted = clf.predict(['one about cheese'])
print(predicted)
# ['cheese']
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to build the Bag-of-Words representation of each new example you want to run prediction over, transforming the example with the same pipeline you created to train the model.